# How Spring AMQP always ensure connection to Master Queue Node in Rabbit MQ Cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a 3 Node Rabbit MQ setup. All the queue are being created at runtime.

If i don't mirror the queues then a particular queue will be created on suppose Node1 and will not be present in Node2 and Node3

Now if i use the Spring AMQP client as then how will it ensure the the queue1 which is available on Node 1, It will always connect to Node 1 to access the queue1

```
rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" addresses="host1, host2, host3" username="username" password="password"
```

The other way is to use ha-mode all where each queue when created on any node will get replicate to the rest of the Nodes as well. This will ensure HA and 100% Guarantee of message to be consume whether the client connects on any of the nodes. ***BUT ITS A NOT A DESIRED OR GOOD SOLUTION***

I am looking for the solution if no HA policy if being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation about Queue Affinity and the LocalizedQueueConnectionFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#queue-affinity).

While it was designed for HA queues, it will work for any queue and connect to the node that hosts the queue (if available).

It requires the management plugin; it uses the REST API to determine which node hosts a queue.

If the queue is durable and the hosting node is down, set `missingQueuesFatal` to `false` so the listener container will continue to keep trying. Missing queues are treated as fatal by default and the container will stop.